# How can I push a button with VR hands?

Tags: unity, virtual-reality, oculus

New programmer here.

I am currently trying to create a sample game in Unity (2019.2.11f1) where I push a button using the VR hands of my Oculus Rift (the hands follow my controllers). I can't believe how difficult is to find documentation or tutorials for said task. I've tried to read documentation but I'm at a loss here.

I have tried putting sphere colliders on the Hands, and tried to use raycast, with no success. I use the `localAvatar` with both grabbers as children, and the avatar is itself child of the `OVR Player Controller` prefab you get when you download the Oculus asset from the store.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to [gamedev.se]! Please note that I have removed from the Question the request to external links/references/examples because that is considered off-topic here.

Comment: "I have tried putting sphere colliders on the Hands, and tried to use raycast, with no success." - Excellent! But don't just tell us you did it. Show us what you did and how the results differed from what you want. We can't help you fix the mistakes in your implementation if we can't see your implementation.